# Attempting to determine intent of $(X^{\text{T}} X)^{-1} (X^{\text{T}} Y)$, possibly related to multiple regression

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I've inherited a code base that is pretty much undocumented. Some of this code is grouped in a module named "Regression". This particular function is named "getCoefMatrix".

For a 2D matrix $X$ (with the last column being all "1"s, somewhat like a design matrix) and a 1D matrix $Y$, the following following is returned by the function:

$$(X^{\text{T}} X)^{-1} (X^{\text{T}} Y)$$

I'm not sure just what is being calculated here, especially given the context ("Regression.getCoefMatrix").

Answer (score 0):

It looks like related questions ended up saving the day. This is answered in depth in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268416/closed-form-for-coefficients-in-multiple-regression-model?rq=1).

In short, this is indeed multiple regression, as it is the least squares estimate ($\hat\beta$).